# Can I get the surrounding text from selected text in Android?

Tags: android

I would like to develop a translator application on Android, which translates not only the selected (*ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT*-ed) text but also the whole sentence.
For example: I am reading an article in a browser in a foreign language, and I am reading the following sentence:

Ich liebe dich, du liebst mich nicht.

I select the word "liebe", then I select my application from the context menu (In the picture, Copy with clipnote is shown, imagine here the name of my application) then I want to translate not only the word "liebe" but also the whole sentence. (So the string Ich liebe dich, du liebst mich nicht.)

[image]

Is it possible?

I am expecting to get the surrounding text of the selected world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible?

Not really. `ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT` definitely does not support apps obtaining arbitrary amounts of text beyond what was selected, for obvious privacy and security reasons.

I cannot rule out the possibility of creating what you are seeking via an `AccessibilityService`. However, before you go down that path, you may wish to discuss your plans with qualified legal counsel, who can advise you regarding the laws in your area and the terms of your preferred app distribution platform(s).

Comment: Thank you, It would be only for personal usage. Probably I will select a bigger text chunk that contains the sentence itself and parse the sentence in my application.